# Remote Validation with datetime parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Have an MVC 5 project,

my project is multilingual,
my issue is with when I use a remote validation and send a parameter of type DateTime, the server is not paying attention to CurrentCulture it uses the default culture ("en-US").

I have many forms in my project most of them have DateTime objects and it's working well.

here's a sample of my code:

> View Model Property

```
    [Display(Name = "CompetitionCycleStartDate", ResourceType = typeof(Competitions))]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = Formats.UKFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "CompetitionCycleStartDateRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Competitions))]
[Remote("CheckStartDateCross", "CompetitionCycle", ErrorMessageResourceName = "CycleStartDateCrossMsg", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Competitions))]
            public DateTime CompetitionCycleStartDate { get; set; }
```

> Remote validation method

```
public ActionResult CheckStartDateCross(DateTime CompetitionCycleStartDate)
        {
            var isItNotCross = competitionCycleService.CheckIfStartDateNotCross(CompetitionCycleStartDate);
            return Json(isItNotCross, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

> Setting culture code

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    var routeData = requestContext.RouteData;
    if (routeData.Values.ContainsKey("MS_DirectRouteMatches"))
    {
        routeData = ((IEnumerable<RouteData>)routeData.Values["MS_DirectRouteMatches"]).First();
        CurrentLanguageCode = routeData?.Values["lang"] as string;
    }
    else if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] != null && requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] as string != "null")
    {
        CurrentLanguageCode = (string)routeData.Values["lang"];
    }
    if (CurrentLanguageCode != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(CurrentLanguageCode);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Invalid language code '{CurrentLanguageCode}'.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar");
    }
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

> Web.Config

```
<globalization culture="en-GB"></globalization>
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179/ (sending data in any format other than iso8601, especially locale-specific or without timezone is asking for trouble. Now you have one :) )

Comment: i sent it as string and it works, but i need more information about what cause this issue